# find active tab or URL or IntPtr windowHandle in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have an IEView that has many IEWindows and each IEWindow has an IETab and each IETab has the  window handle of the tab and the url of that tab in it.

I currently use

```
 WindowStateChanged(uint dwWindowStateFlags, uint dwValidFlagsMask)
```

to know when tabs change.  What I can't figure out is on startup when there is already an IE there in existence, what is the current active tab?  If I could just get the active url, I could find the active tab OR if I could just get the active tab window handle, I could get the active tab.  Maybe I should climb the tree and try to getSelectedTabIndex to determine the active tab as I know my IETabs got added in the exact order that they are in IE which I thought was interesting and probably not a co-incidence.

does anyone know how to either

1. get the active tab handle OR
2. get the active tab's url so I can look up the tab OR
3. how I would go about getting the tab control and getting the index of the selected tab
4. or perhaps find the focused IntPtr handle since the window at this time is coming into focus and hopefully the tab is considered the thing in focus?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: `WindowStateChanged` is the only API that exposes this information.

Comment: hmmm, I am not so sure you are right, I currently can get the tabs of another win32 application and am wondering if I can get that to work on a IE window now.  starting to use winspy++ but not sure I see anything as of yet.....or I wonder if focus there might be something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmmm, I am not sure this is correct or not, but the selected Tab is ALWAYS the last Classname=FrameTab in the components list using Winspy++.  As I switch tabs, the order of the list changes and the selected one is always last.  This is for IE 9...not sure about the other versions.

So, I think using IntPtr handle from tab, I can go up the tree to Classname=IEFrame and get it's children of type Classname=FrameTab and the last one is the selected tab.